# To get rid of heavy archive logs in PostgreSQL 9.1

Tags: postgresql-9.1

In our production server which is having PostgreSQL 9.1 installed, too heavy archive logs are being generated, approximately 41 GB/day. Heavy updates, deletes and inserts are the cause of this. Can anyone help us to reduce the amount of archive log generation in our production server?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to analyze again that log. You can reduce the things that database will be log.
Some of them are:

1. `log_statement`: Controls which SQL statements are logged. You don't need to log all statement. It can be switched to `none`.
2. `client_min_messages`: can be set to `ERROR`
3. `log_min_messages`: can be set to `ERROR`
4. `log_min_duration_statement`: can be set to a `-1` - this means disable it.

All of them are store in file configuration `postgresql.conf`

You can read more document [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-logging.html).

Hopefully this answer will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mabu Kloesen. But I am not talking about postgresql alert log. I am talking about transaction logs

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry, I'm misunderstood.
So, did you try to use gzip for your archive log?
The command we used in archive_command is
`test ! -f /where/you/store/archive/%f && gzip < %p > /where/you/store/archive/%f`

Comment: Is that you mean that before copying it will compress the file size?

Comment: Yes, basically the xlog will store all thing you do with database for recovering, so I think, we can't reduce that. We just can reduce the archive file. One of them is compress it.

Comment: Thank you buddy. I will try this approach as soon as possible and keep you posted on this

Comment: Okay, try it, and please note the command if you want to recovery 

`gunzip < /where/you/store/archive/%f > "%p"`

Comment: Is there any way to reduce the number of archive logs generation ?

Comment: Sorry, You can get more document here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-ARCHIVE-COMMAND

I think basically you can reduce the number but the file size will be bigger, so the total size is not changed.